# Enabling filestream on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, filestream

When trying to enable filestream to a SQL Server 2008 I've got this message:

> There was an unknown error applying the FILESTREAM settings. Check the parameters are valid.

And now in the FILESTREAM tab of the properties of said server I read:

> A previous FILESTREAM configuration attempt was incomplete. FILESTREAM may be in an inconsistent state until re-configured

Do you know what might have gone wrong? What parameters is it taking about? Do I need to reset anything to be able to try again?

I've tried with [filestream_enable.vbs](http://www.codeplex.com/SQLSrvEngine/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FileStreamEnable&referringTitle=Home), but that failed too:

```
c:\Users\pupeno\Downloads\EnableFilestream>cscript filestream_enable.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Machine: .
Instance: MSSQLSERVER
Level: 3
ShareName:

Current Filestream configuration:

InstanceName = MSSQLSERVER
AccessLevel  = 0
ShareName    = MSSQLSERVER
RsFxVersion  = 0103

Calling method EnableFilestream with new level

Method failed: hr = -2147024894


New Filestream configuration:

InstanceName = MSSQLSERVER
AccessLevel  = 0
ShareName    = MSSQLSERVER
RsFxVersion  = 0103
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-install SQL Server, but if someone else is having the same problem, I'd recommend trying the other solutions first. Just don't have a lot of hope.

Comment: Re-installing Sql Server is definitely not the right way to go in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before, and what solved it for us was using the command line tool to enable it from the command line. You can get the tool [here](http://www.codeplex.com/SQLSrvEngine/Wiki/View.aspx?title=FileStreamEnable&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: Unfortunately, that's also failing.

Answer (score 0):

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=473895 talks about [this hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937444).

Does that help?